# Redirect using mod_rewrite in Apache

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

How to redirect from:

```
http://www.test.com/category/kariera/
```

to

```
http://www.test.com/kariera/
```

using mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 1):

mod_rewrite is not used for this kind of purpose. It is usually used when you have a generic requirement. You can use a lighter on performance module called *mod_alias*

Use the following lines in *.htaccess*

```
Redirect 301 /category/kariera/ /
```

OR

```
Redirect 301 /category/kariera/ http://www.test.com/kariera/
```

Make sure *mod_alias* is enabled.